# PyQt signal when layer name is changed in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5, layer-name

[image]

Use this when layers are added, deleted, or their order is changed.
Can you get a signal when a layer name is changed?

```py
QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(self.polygonList)
QgsProject.instance().layerRemoved.connect(self.polygonList)
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().layerOrderChanged.connect(self.polygonList)
```

Comment: @Taras `nameChanged` of `QgsMapLayer` is related to specific layer, not to layer tree. I guess OP asks how to get a signal when **any** layer name has changed.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`nameChanged`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html#a3d1c3582f58e93f71e70bd1c0b00005a) signal of `QgsLayerTreeNode` class.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def name_changed(node, name):
    print(f"New Name: {name}")
    
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().nameChanged.connect(name_changed)
```

It also works on groups. Therefore, you may need to check if it is a layer.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayerTreeLayer

def name_changed(node, name):
    if isinstance(node, QgsLayerTreeLayer): # <--
        print(f"New Name: {name}")

QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().nameChanged.connect(name_changed)
```